# how to get non-friends messages in ChattAR iOS app

Tags: facebook, quickblox

In [ChattAR](https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios) iOS app can we get non-friends messages (if somebody who is not my friend on Facebook send me a message) in `MessagesViewController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we can't, this is Facebook Chat API restriction http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/